# "Disproved" an exercise in limiting probabilities, where did I go wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let ${X_i}$ be iid rv's with Pareto(1,2) distribution. Let $Y_n =
>  max(X_1,..X_n)$. Show that $Y_n \rightarrow 1 $ in probability as $n
>  \rightarrow \infty$

The basis of this "counter-proof" is that convergence in distribution and convergence in probability are equivalent (iff) if they converge to a degenerate/constant distribution. Now:
$$P(Y_n<y) =P(max(X_1,..X_n)<y) = P(X_1 < y,X_2 <y,...,X_n<y) = (F_X(y))^n $$
so the distribution function of $Y_n$ is
$$F_{Y_n}(y) = (1-\frac{1}{y^2})^n$$ which for any fixed $y$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. (Notice that $y \geq1$ always, since $x\geq1$ by the Pareto distribution). Thus $Y_n$ does not converge in distribution to 1, and by the quoted theorem it thus can't converge to 1 in probability either. I don't think I actually "disproved" the exercise, though I can't see where my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: If I understand well then we have $1\leq X_1\leq Y_n$. So  $Y_n\to 1$ can only be true if $X_1=1$ (which is definitely not the case). Should in not be about $\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)$?

Comment: I agree! That would make more sense.

Comment: If $Z_n=\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ then $P(Z_n\geq1)=1$ and for $x>1$ we find $P(Z_n>x)=x^{-2n}\to0$ by increasing $n$. So $Z_n\to1$ in distribution and you are ready.